# Estimation filter

Tags: kalman-filters

Can anybody explain me the basic difference between kalman filter and particle filter? For the process of estimation which is the best filter to be ised among them and why? Please provide some example for the same. Thank you

Comment: Hi! Welcome. Your question is too broad and essentially feels like you're offloading your essay homework on us. Can you please explain in your own words what you've been able to research on the difference, so that we can *help* you from there?

Comment: @marcus I have been suggested to use particle filter for position estimation and kalman filtering for vehicle speed filtering. I cannot understand the requirement for 2 different estimation filter. Can you please throw some light on both of these filter so it would help in choosing the correct estimation filter?

Comment: so, you are aware of the way both work, right? Because this is the case where half an hour on each wikipedia article will bring you waaaaaay forward in your problem.

Comment: Yes. But, still requirement is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences but I would say that the basic difference is a Kalman Filter operates under the assumption that you have a linear state space and linear measurement model corrupted by Gaussian Noise.  A Gaussian process is completely specified by its mean and variance.  The state variables are a mean vector. The state is a sufficient statistic.

In a particle filter, you are trying to track the probability density itself. The assumptions are more general and in general, not all probability densities have a sufficient statistic. Some books call this a infinite state filter.

Where you use one over the other depends a lot on the problem because many problems, while not Gaussian, are reasonably approximated by a finite state filter.  Modifications to the Kalman such as the Extended Kalman Filter and Unscented Kalman Filter fall into this category.

A properly tuned particle filter could outperform an EKF and UKF in terms of tracking but one needs to trade off the considerably more complex implementation.